# Bcc function in drupal 9 mail

Tags: php, drupal, phpmailer, drupal-8

Using below snippet I am trying to send email by Bcc-ing users:

My hook_mail snippet is as below:

```
    function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $options = array(
    'langcode' => $message['langcode'],
  );
  $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes';
  $message['from'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
  $message['headers']['bcc'] = $params['context']['Bcc'];
  $message['subject'] = $params['context']['subject'];
  $message['body'][] = $params['context']['message'];
}
```

On the hook_entity_presave, based on bundle type I want to send out notification to a group of audience:

```
function mymodule_node_presave(EntityInterface $entity)
{
    if ($entity->bundle() == 'resources') {
        notify_new_resources($entity, 'created');
    }
}
```

On the method body:

```
function notify_new_resources(EntityInterface $entity, $mode)
{
$params['context']['subject'] = t('A new resource has been created!');
$params['context']['message'] = 'A new resource has been created blah blah blah...';
$to = 'myaddress@somedomain.com';
$params['context']['bcc'] = $s_recipients; //I do some code to get the $s_recipeints list
\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail('system', 'mail', $to, $langcode, $params);
}
```

This snippet doesn't work. Meaning, email goes out only to the "To" address and not to "Bcc". Any help on how this can be fixed please?

**UPDATE:** I am able to figure out between hook_mail and hook_mail_alter. So I have modified my code snippets above.

Comment: I’m confused about your first function, where does `$bcc` come from?

Comment: Alright. I am actually confused between hook_mail and hook_mail_alter. So I tried to pass on the $bcc as a variable in hook_mail_alter. Also on my code that snippet comes after the function. I know this is wrong. Can you guide on a proper fix for this?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Modified my snippet above. pls check

Comment: The next thing I'm seeing is that in your function you are using the `bcc` key but in your hook you are using `Bcc` as the key

Comment: @ChrisHaas is right, `$message['headers']['bcc'] = $params['context']['bcc'];` in the hook_mail should fix the issue. Header names are not case sensitive, but PHP array keys are.